# Easy Mailchimp Extender & easy fancy box plugin for Wordpress-Conflicting

Tags: wordpress, plugins, fancybox, conflict, mailchimp

I'm new to these forums, I actually found them because I've been having a problem with my wordpress website, as two of my plugins are conflicting and I can't resolve the issue.

I'm using the Easy Mailchimp Extender plugin and the easy fancy box plugin, though there is a conflict between the two.  Basically my images open fine with the easy fancybox plugin, but only if mailchimp is not active.  If mailchimp is active, fancybox is disabled, and my homepage media slider doesn't display properly.

You can view my website (and see the homepage issue here):

http://www.martinbrooksmusic.com/

I found the forum through a google search because hugegoudaface had the same problem as me (which is mentioned as the 4th answer on this thread) - though he doesn't explain how he resolved the issue in a way I understand...

[MailChimp jQuery Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540770/mailchimp-jquery-conflict)

I'd massively appreciate any help to resolve this issue.  I'm not an experienced programmer though, so will probably need things explained in quite a basic way.

Thanks very much!

Martin